# How can I destructure a vector of &str?

Tags: rust

My situation:

```
let mut str_vect = Vec::new();
str_vect.push("a");
str_vect.push("b");
str_vect.push("c");
let [a, bc @ ..] = str_vect[..];
println!("{:?} {:?}", a, bc);
```

https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=8e4c47b024e0c871676626069ec07d52

I get this error:

> the size for values of type `[&str]` cannot be known at compilation time

Why is that? Can I somehow destructure of `Vec` of `&str`?

Comment: Why are you using edition 2018 in the playground? Is it by mistake?

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Definitely, thanks for making me notice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just add a `&`: `v[..]` is a DST (`[T]`, **not** `&[T]`). This is fine as long as we only access individual elements, but for rest patterns (`..`), that produce a slice - they will have to produce `[T]`, too, and that is unsized. If you match against `&[T]`, on the other hand, the rest pattern also gives `&[T]` (another possibility is to use `ref` - `ref bc @ ..`, but I would not recommend that).

```rust
let [a, bc @ ..] = &str_vect[..];
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=4172bcdee170a1d289c0764f19239c5d).

However, this fails with:

```
error[E0005]: refutable pattern in local binding: `&[]` not covered
 --> src/main.rs:6:8
  |
6 |    let [a, bc @ ..] = &str_vect[..];
  |        ^^^^^^^^^^^^ pattern `&[]` not covered
  |
  = note: `let` bindings require an "irrefutable pattern", like a `struct` or an `enum` with only one variant
  = note: for more information, visit https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch18-02-refutability.html
  = note: the matched value is of type `&[&str]`
help: you might want to use `if let` to ignore the variant that isn't matched
  |
6 |    let (a, bc) = if let [a, bc @ ..] = &str_vect[..] { (a, bc) } else { todo!() };
  |    ++++++++++++++++                                  ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

That is because any slice pattern except `[..]` is [refutable](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch18-02-refutability.html) - that is, may fail. What if `str_vect` (theoretically) has zero elements? We cannot bind the first element in that case! You need `if let` or `match` to handle that case.

Answer (score 5):

Another solution, which is definitely **not** destructuring, but which is easier to read in my opinion because the name expresses the intention, would rely on [`split_first()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.split_first).

```rust
    let (a, bc) = str_vect.split_first().unwrap();
```

Of course, some appropriate error handling should be considered instead of unwrap.

And yes, the other answer is far better because it explains in details the origin of the reported error (I just upvoted it ;^).

Comment: [`split_first()` itself is implemented via destructuring](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.61.0/src/core/slice/mod.rs.html#213) :) If all you want is to access the first/rest, then it is better. But it may be just a simplified example.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman good to know, thanks a lot for the insight.

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to use iterators:

```rust
fn main() {
   let mut str_vect = Vec::new();
   str_vect.push("a");
   str_vect.push("b");
   str_vect.push("c");
   let (a, bc) = {
        let mut it = str_vect.into_iter();
        (it.next(), it)
   };
   println!("{:?} {:?}", a.unwrap(), bc.collect::<Vec<_>>());
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=bda60c4ea89d64d89c9321f281c29aa5)

Of course this makes you have to check and/or collect to whatever you need later on. You could just use the iterator if you need. Notice I used `into_iter` which consumes the vector, but you could use `iter` to just work with references instead too.